# Maximum doPost()/ajax data Size

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-apps-script

I've been creating Drive files for a while now with Published Pages and Apps Script, but now has arrived a demand to create them from an external link, and I've created a Snippet to get base64 data from a POST and create a Drive file for it, it **works great for <8kb data**, anything greater than that throws me an `GET`error which my limited knowledge can't debug.

The only [limitation that's near this is the 8kb for headers size](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), but this ain't it, or I'm sending this as a header?

Here's the setup:

Published Code.gs:

```
function doPost( e ) {
  var returnMsg;

  try{
    var splitBase = (e.parameter.base64).split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:',''),
        nomeArq = (new Date()).getTime();

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(nomeArq);

    var file = DriveApp.createFile(ss);

    returnMsg = file.getId();
  }catch(e){
    returnMsg = 'Erro: ' + e.toString();
  }

  return ContentService.createTextOutput( returnMsg );
}
```

Ajax call on an external website that works (<8kb data):

```
function sendPostData() {
    params = 'base64=data:image/png;base64,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';
    params = params.replace(/\+/g,'%2b');

    url = #ThePublishedUrl#/exec;

    $.ajax({
        crossDomain : true,
        url : url,
        type : 'post',
        data : params,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        contentType : 'jsonp',
        processData : false,
        success : function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert("some error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: After doing some tests, I uploaded data payloads using POST methods of up to 24MB without issues. Reached a "Max file size" limit with sizes beyond 24mb, but seems related to Drive rather than GAS. A year after your question, I was also looking for related information: [Max size for POST request sent to webapps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315816/max-size-for-post-request-sent-to-webapps).