# Max size for POST request sent to webapps

Tags: google-apps-script

I use doPost() function callbacks a lot in my Google Apps Script projects.

Have rencently been looking for documentation regarding the max size to be admitted by GAS webapps expecting POST requests, to no avail. In the limits and quotas page, it mentions url fetch related data, which I presume refers to the URL fetch api calls, and not payloads of incoming POST request.

Anyone found info regarding this, has done tests, or can share any insight?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone posted a similar problem where it maxed out at 8kB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730493/maximum-dopost-ajax-data-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some tests, I uploaded data payloads using POST methods of up to 24MB without issues. Reached a "Max file size" limit with sizes beyond 24mb, but seems related to Drive rather than GAS.

Comment: An example script published publicly would help others.