# Does getBlob() OR getDataAsString() have a maximum file size in Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I have referenced this solution: [blob.getDataAsString() Size Limit in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42069003/9878092), but I am still unsure about what is specifically causing my error, "File NAME.csv exceeds the maximum file size". In my Google App Maker application, the user uploads an Excel CSV file that is 56.5 MB, and I am curious about whether getBlob() or getDataAsString() has a maximum file size of 50 MB. Thank you very much.

Comment: An error message will flag the line that causes the error. If you have multiple statements on the same line, consider breaking them apart to better determine the root cause. PS: you probably have to break up the Excel file before trying to use Apps Script on it.

Comment: I just found out that getDataAsString() seems to have a maximum file size, while getBlob() does not.

Comment: @Eric Did you find documentation for the maximum file size? Is there any way to get around this problem?